# list specific category in json object

Tags: json

```
var food = {"fruit" :[{"name":"banana"},{"name":"apple"},{"name":"orange"},], "veg" :[{"name":"carrot"},{"name":"brocolli"},{"name":"cabbage"}]};

for(var i in food) {
    for(var j in food[i]) {
        var listAll = food[i][j];    
        console.log(listAll);       
    }
}
```

I want to get the list of the fruit/veg in my json object for struggling to and can only get a list of all items in my object.

How do I get for example:

> banana,apple,orange OR carrot,brocolli,carrot

Answer (score 0):

You have the logic of iterating the properties correctly. But when you refer to "listAll", it is referring to the object within. eg: {"name":"banana"};

To get just the name, reference that property:

```
var food = {"fruit" :[{"name":"banana"},{"name":"apple"},{"name":"orange"},], "veg" :[{"name":"carrot"},{"name":"brocolli"},{"name":"cabbage"}]};

for(var i in food) {
    for(var j in food[i]) {
        var listAll = food[i][j].name;    
        console.log(listAll);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks but i solved it.

this was what i was after -

```
for(var i in food.fruit) {
    for(var j in food.fruit[i]) {
        var listAll = food.fruit[i][j];    
        console.log(listAll);       
    }
}
```